# Specify a correlation between two cross-classified random variables in a mixed-effect model

Tags: glmmtmb, crossed-random-effects

I posted this question in a different version on R-sig-mixed-models and received no reply. I am trying my luck here. I am trying to emulate an ANOVA-based approach to analyzing round-robin data with a mixed-effect model. In the example data below, every person (Perceiver) in a group of 10 people rates how much they like all other people (Targets) in the group. I specified a cross-classified mixed effect model, with Perceiver and Target as random variables, as follows (including the data set taken from the tripleR package):

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(TripleR)
data("multiLikingLong")
x <- multiLikingLong
x <- x[x$group.id == 1, ]

m1 <- glmmTMB(liking_a ~ 1 + (1|perceiver.id) + (1|target.id), x)
summary(m1)
```

Yet, how can I specify a correlation between Perceiver and Target effects (Do people who tend to rate others as more likable are rated by others as more likable)? (I can approximate it by extracting the effects with `ranef`, but I am looking for estimation within the model).

I know how to force `glmmTMB` to specify a correlation between random variables, but my attempt is gibberish. What I am missing is how to set this model correctly. For example, I can create a gibberish correlation as follows:

```
x$id <- as.factor(row.names(x))
m2 <- glmmTMB(liking_a ~ 1 + (0 + perceiver.id + target.id |id), x)
summary(m2)
```

Finally, the results should replicate more or less the ANOVA results.

```
RR(liking_a ~ perceiver.id*target.id, data = x)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seemingly looking for is the "generalized reciprocity correlation" from a Social Relations Model.

You don't specify the outcome type, but I'll make a preliminary assumption that the "scores" are ordered categorical outcomes.

If you're content to make the assumption that is common among psychologists that these outcomes can be treated as a continuous (gaussian) outcome, then there are prepackaged software alternatives that can fit this model including:

1. [Stat-JR](http://apknight.org/tag/social-relations-model/)
2. [A Shiny app](http://apknight.org/tag/social-relations-model/)

If you want to model the outcome as ordered (with an ordered logit or ordered probit, for example), those sort of applications are starting to appear in the [literature](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssa/advance-article/doi/10.1093/jrsssa/qnad115/7260780), but you'll probably need to code up your own model in Stan, JAGS, WinBUGS, etc.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your quick and detailed answer. Indeed, I am assuming that the outcome variable could be considered continuous and trying to estimate generalized reciprocity correlation. The apps suggested appear limited to observed outcome. I would like to extend it to latent outcome (with multiple indicators) and use mixed-effects to add complex set of fixed effects. Do I understand correctly that it is not feasible without a set of dummy codes as used in the Shiny app?

Comment: If fitting the model in Stan, JAGS, or BUGS, it would be fairly trivial to extend it to a latent outcome with multiple indicators. But I don't know of any prepackaged apps that implement that.